Boto3 get_cost_and_usage stopped to work inside codebuild
I have a script inside codebuild that get aws costs with Boto3 - get_cost_and_usage() from cost explorer.
The script worked fine until 28 of Jule 2024. After this date the script fails with "Rate limit exceeded" that means "too many requests". But it's first request to 'ce' in the script, I see no reason to this error.
session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client('ce')
response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={'Start': start_date, 'End': end_date},
        Granularity='MONTHLY',
        Metrics=['UnblendedCost'])

botocore.errorfactory.LimitExceededException: An error occurred (LimitExceededException) when calling the GetCostAndUsage operation: Rate limit exceeded
At the same time same script works fine locally, outside of codebuild.
I tried to downgrade boto3 and botocore, copy script to another region, change OS of codebuild, add sleep(1) here and there - nothing helped.
